# ip addr output: mgt: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000

Tags: linux, ip, ip-address, nic, ifconfig

I am trying to retrieve the ip addr of the linux system.  What is the meaning of "qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000" ?

Answer (score 0):

qdisc = queue discipline type, in this case, a clasfull multiqueue,
Multiqueue is a feature is otherwise referenced as RSS (Receive-Side-Scaling) which basically is distributing the load of packet processing among several cores. Further reading: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/networking/scaling.rst

```
state = interface state, UP, DOWN, etc
qlen = queue length, in this case 1000 packets.
```

More general information on the use and output of the IP ADDR command can be found here http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-address.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).